# Google Drive HTTP 403 “Access Not Configured” error

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, google-drive-api

I'm attempting to install the DrEdit sample app for Salesforce onto GAE. The app runs, but saving or opening a file results in an HTTP 403 "Access Not Configured Error".

I have also attempted to use the values for API Access>Client ID for web applications. The Google Drive SDK> OAuth Client ID has also been set variously to the Drive SDK and web app Client IDs. but, After enabling both (Api, SDK) in Api access service i am still getting same error.

Comment: Can you give a complete error message please, what is the body of your 403? (also people voting to close, this is a perfectly reasonable question)

Answer (score 2):

Can you make sure that you register your application on the Google APIs Console and enable the Drive API and SDK for it first?

It's all described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/register

Then make sure that you use your Client ID and Client Secret in DrEdit's configuration file.