# Configuring Google Drive API and SDK

Tags: javascript, apex-code, google-drive-api

I'm attempting to install the DrEdit sample app for Salesforce onto GAE. The app runs, but saving or opening a file results in an HTTP 403 "Access Not Configured Error".

I have also attempted to use the values for API Access>Client ID for web applications. The Google Drive SDK> OAuth Client ID has also been set variously to the Drive SDK and web app Client IDs.
but, After enabling both (Api, SDK) in Api access service i am still getting same error.

Comment: you already asked the same question, didn't you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Drive HTTP 403 “Access Not Configured” error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597993/google-drive-http-403-access-not-configured-error)

Comment: OK since the user is not deleting his question I'll post a duplicate answer a well :)

Answer (score 1):

Please see duplicate post about this: [Google Drive HTTP 403 “Access Not Configured” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597993/google-drive-http-403-access-not-configured-error)

---

Copy of the answer given:

Can you make sure that you register your application on the Google APIs Console and enable the Drive API and SDK for it first?

It's all described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/register

Then make sure that you use your Client ID and Client Secret in DrEdit's configuration file.